# How to prevent TFS 2013 from locking binary files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

We work with TFS 2013 with Visual Studio 2013, and using Gated Check-In. With Gated Check-In it's impossible to preserve pending changes locally, [if one of the files is locked](http://www.neovolve.com/2011/07/18/unable-to-preserve-pending-changes-on-gated-check-in/).

We don't use locks at all, but:

> If you check out a file that is of a type that is treated as binary, Visual Studio Team Foundation Server might automatically lock it because binary files cannot be merged. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490760(v=vs.100).aspx))

We want to configure TFS to not lock binary files. How can we do this?

Comment: You shouldn't be putting binaries into source control. Use a package manager.

Comment: @DanielMann: Not `binaries`; binary files. PNG files, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio, use the "Team" menu, then "Team Project Collection Settings", then "Source Control..."

From there you can change which types allow [File Merging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181457.aspx).

You might also want to see if "[Enable multiple check-out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869.aspx)" is checked. You can find this in Visual Studio, use the "Team" menu, then "Team Project Settings", then "Source Control..."